# Twitter bootstrap grid: is it possible to simulate smaller screen by adding class to container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

Does Twitter Bootstrap 3 provide a built-in way to "simulate" a smaller screen by adding a css class to grid container?

My use case is that I want to display an section of html using bootstrap's grid normally on a large screen, but I want to reuse the same snippet for displaying in a modal (which is much narrower). For example, say I have this html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">One</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">Two</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a built-in class I can add to the `.container` element (like `.simulate-sm`) to force the columns to display using the `sm` grid definition, even if it's on `md` screen? The html above is just an example: my real-world html has a large number of rows and more varied column combinations, which makes me hesitant to try to massage the column classes  individually.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just use `col-lg-12` in your example?

Comment: Not really. I want `One` and `Two` to appear next to one another on a large screen, but stacked on a small screen (this is easy with the out-of-the-box grid). But I also want to able to add a class to the `.container` to make `One` and `Two` stacked, even when on a large screen. I'll make an edit to my question to make this more clear.

Comment: please see here http://responsive.victorcoulon.fr/ just grab RWDBookmarklet and drop on link bar and it helps you to easy emulate smaller screen

Comment: wouldn't you want .simulate-xs to force xs, not sm, and .simualate-sm to force sm? assuming so, I can show you how to do it... but it's not built in:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing built in, but with the right CSS (including descendant classes), you can make a single added custom class do all the work for you. In your specific example, you would add .simulate-sm to the .modal-body div like so:

```
<div class="modal-body simulate-sm">      
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">One</div>
....
```

and some custom CSS:

```
.simulate-sm .col-sm-12{width:100%}
.simulate-sm .col-sm-8{width:75%}
.simulate-sm .col-sm-6{width:50%}
.simulate-sm .col-sm-4{width:25%} /* extrapolate as needed */
```

Do this for whatever column classes you've used in your original code, doing the basic math to figure out % width. (i.e. the same as Bootstrap's).

The combination of descendant specificity and using this on the modal-body means it ONLY overrides Bootstrap's styling when within a modal (to which you've added the .simulate-* class).

**Here is an example: http://www.bootply.com/KhNbrdUzoE**

Comment: ps- you could also do this with NO custom class, by using .modal-body as the parent in all your custom CSS. But then you could not turn it on/off on content as needed, so seems a little reckless...

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite visualize your problem, and I've never had to do this myself, but I feel like this snippet from the documentation is relevant to your need:

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, applying any .col-md- class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg- class is not present.

If you remove the col-md-6 class definition it sounds like the col-sm-12 definition will take effect for all form factors equal to or larger than the small screen.

Apologies if the answer is irrelevant. Was a complete shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to emulate what it would look like on a mobile device, most browsers have emulators. For example in chrome, you would inspect an element and there is an emulator option on the bottom near the console. In terms of emulating a screen "bigger" than yours, there are websites that allow you to view your webpage from a different resolution. With a quick google search here is an emulator: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/